# Keyboard button click to trigger some functions?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I'm creating WinForm program using C#. I'd like to trigger some functions with combination of keyboard clicks like "Alt+S" or "Alt+Shift+S" even when the focus is not in the program itself (not on any Forms).

Is that possible? If so, where should I put the functions, and the code where it detects the button combination?

Thanks!

Comment: have you even tried some search on this? there are tons of such code out there. The key words for you: `global keyboard hook`, `register hot keys`

Comment: I did some researches, and yes there are some solutions. But most of them only accepts the hot keys when Form is loaded, which means if the focus is out of form, it can't be triggered.

Comment: OK...more specifically, search for either `wh_keyboard_ll` or `registerhotkey` (all as one word).  The second approach will fail if the desired hotkey combo is already registered with another application.  The low level keyboard hook is more complicated but is guaranteed to detect the combination.